# Is there a sound picker app with file browser and audio previews?

Tags: applications, ringtone

In android (at least in Xperia) when you want change a ring-tone (SMS, call, ...) it show you a list of all available audio files in your mobile and SD memories. Choosing a ring from a list of thousands of files is not easy at all. Some apps make it a little easier but not prefect.

Is there any app that:

1. Let me choose ring-tone via a file browser
2. Audio clips can be previewed quickly in its file browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Samsung Galaxy S II (and possibly other similar phones) the stock Music Player app can do this. Just open the MP3 in any file manager, choose to play it with the stock Music Player, hit `menu` and select `Use as...` and `Ringtone`.

Another option is to use [doubleTwist Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.doubleTwist.androidPlayer) to show the music by artist/album and long-press the song you want, then select `Use as ringtone`. This way you don't have to select from one long list, but the downside is you can't use your file manager to browse, you're stuck with artist/album grouping.

Also, you could check out [Ringtone Maker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.herman.ringtone), you can browse files in menu -> Browse.... This also has the ability to play, chop and edit volume/fade.

Comment: Yep can do this in stock ICS as well.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for app similar to "Ringtone picker", with mentioned abilities.

Comment: Ringtone Maker is feature-rich. I prefer a simpler app that just can be used for setting sound by browsing. For now I check your answer accepted. Thanks.